# How to add a notification when data is inserted Wordpress

Tags: datatable, notifications, form-submit, elementor, custom-wordpress-pages

I elementor submission form, and I used custom code to show the data inserted from the table to the custom page.

here's my custom code

$user_id = get_current_user_id();

```
    global $user_login, $current_user; 

    get_currentuserinfo();
    $user_info = get_userdata($current_user->ID);
    if (in_array('customer', $user_info->roles)) { 

         $result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_tablesome_table_2060 where author_id = $user_id AND column_4 = 'Pending'");
    }else {
        $result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_tablesome_table_2060 where column_4 = 'Pending' limit 1");
    }

    foreach ($result as $row) {
        $id = $row->id;
    $users = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_users where ID = '".$row->author_id."'");
        foreach ($users as $rowUsers);
     ?>
         <tr>
             <td style="border-left: none;border-right: none;"><?php echo $rowUsers->display_name ?></td>
             <td style="border-left: none;border-right: none;"><?php echo $row->column_1 ?></td>
             <td style="border-left: none;border-right: none;"><?php echo $row->column_2 ?></td>
             <td style="border-left: none;border-right: none;"><?php echo $row->column_3?></td>
             <td style="border-left: none;border-right: none;"><?php echo $row->column_4 ?></td>
  
                <?php 
                } 
                ?>
```

.......